# Reduntant code (possibly) in Bitcoin script.h

Tags: c++, bitcoin

Looking at the code below I can't understand how it is possible for the IF statement conditional expression to become true. `cnt` is already incremented before the IF statement. Is this not redundant?
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script.h#L594

```
/** Build a script by concatenating other scripts, or any argument accepted by CScript::operator<<. */
template<typename... Ts>
CScript BuildScript(Ts&&... inputs)
{
    CScript ret;
    int cnt{0};

    ([&ret, &cnt] (Ts&& input) {
        cnt++;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>, CScript>) {
            // If it is a CScript, extend ret with it. Move or copy the first element instead.
            if (cnt == 0) {
                ret = std::forward<Ts>(input);
            } else {
                ret.insert(ret.end(), input.begin(), input.end());
            }
        } else {
            // Otherwise invoke CScript::operator<<.
            ret << input;
        }
    } (std::forward<Ts>(inputs)), ...);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Look at the version history for the file. When was `cnt` added? What is the commit message when it's added? Have it ever been initialized another way? Have it ever been used another way?

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug, possibly doesn't change the behaviour though so nobody's noticed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The git-blame on that function is unusual. The entire function was [added as-is 4 months ago](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/4fe29368c0ded0e62f437cab3a7c904f7fd3ad67), was not present prior. It was/is exactly as shown here since inception.

Comment: The commit comment says this is part of "some prep work for Miniscript", so it could simply be unfinished code. Especially considering the commit (linked to by @WhozCraig) doesn't make use of the function. However, even newer commits keep this dubious code, so the author maybe forgot it?  Finding things like this is one good things about open-source and peer-review (and why code-review in general is so important).

Comment: Perhaps you should consider adding an issue about this on Github?